# How do I triple boot Windows 10, Arch Linux, and Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, boot, grub2, boot-loader

here is a bit of the sequence of events:

I have a laptop that came preinstalled with Windows 10. I installed Arch Linux (through Antergos) and dual booted successfully with no issues for some time.

I then downloaded and installed Ubuntu 18.04 to some free space on my drive, and reboot (using the UEFI boot selector) into Arch Linux to upgrade grub using:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

I reboot once more and discover that I am in Ubuntu's grub selector. I am unable to boot into Arch Linux due to a kernel panic, but Ubuntu and Windows 10 are available and boot just fine.

In an attempt to get Arch to boot, I run the following inside Ubuntu but to no avail:

```
update-grub
```

Note:

I intend on keeping Arch as my primary distro (for learning purposes), but need to do some work on Ubuntu, so I'd prefer to stick with the Antergos grub selector.

I am still able to boot into Arch using the UEFI boot selector, and this takes me into my Antergos boot loader which successfully detects and boots all three OS on the system.

I'm sure this is a fairly simplistic solution I just haven't been able to Google properly and need to proceed with some work I have to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do consider running one main OS and then run the others in virtual machines on top of that.

Comment: I've already tried that, but the VM did not meet the specific requirements for the type of workload I need this for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I was able to solve it through a comment by edward torvalds on the OP of this question: [GRUB confuses kernels/initramfs of Ubuntu and Arch Linux installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279278/grub-confuses-kernels-initramfs-of-ubuntu-and-arch-linux-installation?rq=1)

I'll record the solution here:

```
os-prober
sudo mkinitcpio -p linux
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to run multiple operating systems on a single machine is to choose what the main OS is supposed to be, and then run the others in virtual machines on top of that.

This is particularly useful if one or several of the other OSes are just for playing around with.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question and ignores what I have stated. I did not say I would "play around" but that I "needed to do some work."