# GRUB booting issue

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, boot, grub, uefi

I have arch and Ubuntu and windows 10 installed on my system. I had installed Ubuntu before arch hence I already had the grub menu offered by the Ubuntu. But after installing I can see another bootable entry in BIOS.

The grub entry from Ubuntu  shows arch as one of the options to boot, but just loads blank screen. In short I cannot boot from the grub entry of arch from the grub menu installed from Ubuntu.

But from arch's menu I can boot into all the available entries.

How do I fix this issue of not being able to boot into Arch from the grub menu from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this has been answered recently.  [How do I triple boot Windows 10, Arch Linux, and Ubuntu 18.04?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/430531/how-do-i-triple-boot-windows-10-arch-linux-and-ubuntu-18-04)

The accepted answer points to a post by edward Torvalds that resolves a kernel panic issue. I hope it helps
[GRUB confuses kernels/initramfs of Ubuntu and Arch Linux installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279278/grub-confuses-kernels-initramfs-of-ubuntu-and-arch-linux-installation?rq=1)