# How to reset /boot partition

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, dual-boot, grub

I have a bootable USB, which has Ubuntu 20.04 installed in it. Yesterday I tried to make it dual boot with Arch Linux and kinda successfully made it.

At first, I installed Arch Linux with the boot partition mounted to `/mnt/boot`. Then during the installation it failed, but it has already created (overwrote?) initramfs images and kernels in the boot partition. After this, I've formatted the Arch Linux's partition and reinstalled without mounting the boot partition.

Now, the first Ubuntu option in GRUB tries to start Arch Linux and fails, and the Arch Linux option fails too. In order to boot to Ubuntu, I have to use the Advanced options and select the one that specifies the 5.15.0-46-generic kernel.

In order to fix this, I suppose deleting the `amd-ucode.img`, `intel-ucode.img` and `vmlinux-linux` created by Arch Linux and Editing Grub options via `grub-customizer`(removing first options that boot into Arch and fails, moving options that boot into Ubuntu to the top) is safe to do. But how do I fix options to boot into Arch?

(booted into Ubuntu)

Output of `ls /boot -lah`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4,0K Ağu 31 20:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4,0K Ağu 29 23:56 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  50K Tem 15 13:16 amd-ucode.img
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 252K Haz  3 01:48 config-5.13.0-48-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 257K Ağu  4 21:44 config-5.15.0-46-generic
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4,0K Eyl  1 11:59 grub
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4,0K Ağu 31 14:00 grub.bak
-rw-------  1 root root  34M Ağu 31 20:38 initramfs-linux-fallback.img
-rw-------  1 root root 8,7M Ağu 31 20:37 initramfs-linux.img
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   28 Ağu 30 23:25 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.15.0-46-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  62M Ağu 26 11:34 initrd.img-5.13.0-48-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  67M Ağu 30 23:27 initrd.img-5.15.0-46-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   28 Ağu 30 23:25 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.13.0-48-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 5,0M Ağu  9 21:43 intel-ucode.img
drwx------  2 root root  16K Kas  9  2021 lost+found
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 179K Ağu 18  2020 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Ağu 18  2020 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Ağu 18  2020 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root 5,7M Haz  3 01:48 System.map-5.13.0-48-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,0M Ağu  4 21:44 System.map-5.15.0-46-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   25 Ağu 30 23:25 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.15.0-46-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 9,8M Haz  3 01:50 vmlinuz-5.13.0-48-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  11M Ağu  4 21:47 vmlinuz-5.15.0-46-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  11M Ağu 31 20:37 vmlinuz-linux
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   25 Ağu 30 23:25 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.13.0-48-generic
```

boot options from grub-customizer:

[image: boot options from grub-customizer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in luck. I disagree with the answers posted in [GRUB confuses kernels/initramfs of Ubuntu and Arch Linux installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279278/grub-confuses-kernels-initramfs-of-ubuntu-and-arch-linux-installation) and claim Arch and Ubuntu can totally coexist with a shared `/boot` partition.

In `/boot`, these files belong to Arch (kernel and initramfs):

```
initramfs-linux-fallback.img
initramfs-linux.img
vmlinuz-linux
```

These files belong to Ubuntu:

```
initrd.img
initrd.img-*-generic
vmlinuz
vmlinuz-*-generic
```

As you can see, there is no overlap. The only thing both systems are fighting over is the GRUB configuration located at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

I suggest re-generating the GRUB configuration by booting into Ubuntu and executing `sudo update-grub`. As far as I know, this will mistake the Arch kernel for an Ubuntu kernel and produce an invalid entry. I know of no way to stop that from happening, so I reckon you need to just ignore it.

You can proceed to add a new file at `/boot/grub/custom.cfg` and manually define a new entry for booting Arch:

```
menuentry 'Arch Linux' {
  insmod gzio
  insmod ext2
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root <SOMEUUID> ← copy this line from one of the autogenerated Ubuntu entries
  linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux rw root=UUID=<SOMEOTHERUUID> ← put the UUID of your arch linux installation here
  initrd    /boot/initramfs-linux.img
}
```

You can find the UUIDs by running `sudo blkid`.

Have fun trying new distros!

Note: The same thing can happen if you have booted Arch. Then you might have the same problem but the other way around. `update-grub` might create unusable entries for Ubuntu kernels when run from within Arch. I recommend copying one of the working Ubuntu entries from `grub.cfg` to `custom.cfg` just in case.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, `update-grub` thinks Arch's kernel and initramfs images belong to it and update accordingly. But after deleting those files and removing those GRUB entries, it boots into Ubuntu without a problem. For Arch options, I've noticed that it just had `initramfs-linux.img` option, after adding `amd-ucode.img` and `intel-ucode.img` it boots successfully too.(since its purpose is recovery it should be able to boot both in Intel and AMD systems) and a note to your note: Since Ubuntu can handle the GRUB by itself, I didn't even install GRUB on Arch